# How to aggregate two worksheets to one workbook using openXML?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I want to aggregate two different worksheet from another workbooks to one workbook but I don't know how to do that using openXML. I only want to create one workbook with two worksheet. I don't need merge worksheets to one. How to aggregate two worksheets to one workbook using openXML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way which I chose is to open destination file and in loop open iteratively source file with worksheet to be copied. Next, I clone each row from source to destination file with clone node method with deep mode. This cloned row I insert in specific index in destination file worksheet.

The good way is to use EPPlus like in other answer to this question but when I use it with excel file where is defined name (named ranges) it does not work correctly.

Comment: any source code example for ***clone each row from source to destination file*** ?

Answer (score 3):

Copying a worksheet from one workbook to another is easy with [Epplus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) which is available free in Nuget.

Something like this example would copy a worksheet & all it's data from one workbook to another in one go without the need for any separate function to loop over the rows to copy the data:

```
        FileInfo fInfoSrc = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\Source.xlsx");
        FileInfo fInfoDest = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\Destination.xlsx");
        using (var source = new ExcelPackage(fInfoSrc))
        {
            using (var destination = new ExcelPackage(fInfoDest))
            {
                var srcWorksheet = source.Workbook.Worksheets["SourceWorksheet"];
                var destWorksheet = destination.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("destinationWorksheetName", srcWorksheet);
                destination.Save();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems to be a good answer but my program finish execution on the line: "var srcWorksheet = source.Workbook.Worksheets["SourceWorksheet"];".

Comment: I have named range in my excel file and it does not work correctly

Comment: HOw copy rows (not headers) from destinationWorksheetName to SourceWorksheet ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the OpenXml SDK.
A small example how to create a workbook.
Call the second method `AddWorksheet` as many worksheets you need.

```
    private static SpreadsheetDocument CreateWorkbook(Stream stream)
    {
        // Create the Excel workbook
        var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, false);

        // Create the parts and the corresponding objects
        // Workbook
        spreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
        spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
        spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

        // Shared string table
        var sharedStringTablePart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
        sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();
        sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Save();

        // Sheets collection
        spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();
        spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

        // Stylesheet
        var workbookStylesPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
        workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
        workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();


        return spreadSheet;
    }

    private static WorksheetPart AddWorksheet(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet, string name)
    {
        // Add the worksheetpart
        var worksheetPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());


        uint sheetId = 1;
        var sheets = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
        if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Any())
        {
            sheetId = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
        }

        // Add the sheet and make relation to workbook
        var sheet = new Sheet
        {
            Id = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
            SheetId = sheetId,
            Name = name
        };

        sheets.Append(sheet);

        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
        spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

        return worksheetPart;
    }
```

Comment: It's a method to create. I need to populate data from existing worksheets. I need something like "add worksheet to new workbook with data from existing worksheet".

Comment: With my code, you can create a new workbook with many worksheets you need. Than you need a second part that reads the rows from the other workbook and adds it to this new one.

Comment: Moreover this method add at the end of worksheet list new worksheet. Default on Excel there is 3 worksheets already exists.